# how to change PS1 based on what directory i`m working in?

Tags: bash, if-statement, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ps1

I get errors

```
-bash: test1.bash: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'bash: test1.bash: line 5: `elif [$PWD | grep /mnt/c/ !="" OR pwd | grep /mnt/d/ !=""] then
```

i have tried nothing other than the code i written

```
if [$PWD | grep /mnt/c/ =="" OR pwd | grep /mnt/d/ =="" OR pwd | grep /mnt/usb/ ==""] then
    export PS1="$(tput setaf 47)bob$(tput setaf 14):$(tput setaf 47)linux$(tput setaf 14)>"

elif [$PWD | grep /mnt/c/ !="" OR pwd | grep /mnt/d/ !=""] then
    export PS1="$(tput setaf 47)bob$(tput setaf 14):$(tput setaf 47)windows$(tput setaf 14)>"

else then
    export PS1="$(tput setaf 47)bob$(tput setaf 14):$(tput setaf 47)unknows$(tput setaf 14)>"
if
```

i want my PS1 tag to change if i mount a drive for example if im in the directory  `/mnt/c/` or `/mnt/d/` i want PS1 change to windows

Comment: `[$PWD` is always wrong. Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: BTW, questions about interactive shell configuration as opposed to software development are typically a better fit for [unix.se].

Comment: BTW, if you *did* want to use `grep`, a syntactically-valid way to do that might look like `if grep -E -e '/mnt/(c|d|usb)/' <<<"$PWD"; then` -- though using `case` or other shell-internal logic is going too be much more efficient, so I don't actually recommend it in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for:

```
# much more efficient to just run this once rather than every single time you're going to
# change colors.
colors=(
  [14]="$(tput setaf 14)"
  [47]="$(tput setaf 47)"
)

set_prompt() {
  case $PWD in
    /mnt/c/*|/mnt/d/*) os_space=windows ;;
    /mnt/usb/*)        os_space=unknown ;;
    *)                 os_space=linux ;;
  esac
  PS1="${colors[47]}bob${colors[14]}:${colors[47]}${os_space}${colors[14]}>"
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_prompt
```

`[` is not shell syntax -- it's a *command*, also available under the name `test`. Like any other command, you need to put a space between its name and its arguments, and you can only use arguments which that command is specified to expect. When you run `[ foo | bar ]`, you're passing the first instance of `[` only one argument, `foo`, and connecting its stdout to a separate command `bar`; that never makes sense, since `test` doesn't write anything to stdout.

Comment: $ source test1.bash

Comment: -bash: test1.bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''

Comment: 'bash: test1.bash: line 1: `set_prompt() {

Comment: `$'\r'` is a LF character. It means you saved your file in Windows format, not UNIX format. Use a UNIX text editor, or at least one that knows how to write UNIX files.